# unresolved dependence com.google.gson.Gson Android Studio

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, gson

After use implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:24.0.0' i have the message unresolved dependence com.google.gson.Gson, if i try to run the application it work's fine, but i don't have suggest of Gson into android studio, and have a red underline like an error.
I'm tryed implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9' and also don't works.

I'm using kotlin, is all dependences updated.

Comment: Show us the corresponding code.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but a remove firebase-firestore import, in menu -> File -> Invalidate cahe and restart, and after import firebase-firestore again and works fine. Bug

Comment: @GabrielRicci if the issue is resolved, please post an answer with a solution (you can provide the same comment you have provided here, but as an answer)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is self resolved from the following steps as confirmed by [Gabriel Ricci](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9115848/gabriel-ricci)

1. Removing Firebase-firestore import
2. Menu -> File -> Invalidate Cache and restart
3. Import Firebase-firestore again.